# How to connect to a TCP server and pass a Javascript to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I'm definitely a newbie with JS and node.  I have telescope management software called SkyX Pro, and it has the ability to run a TCP Server on port 3040. I can connect to it using Netcat and hand it a Javascript starting with //* Javascript *// this works and allows me to startup cameras and other equipment and send commands for taking pictures etc. The issue is it needs to be run from a batch file which makes getting any information back to an HTML page tough (Like Camera, focuser and filter wheel status and temperatures).

The NC call looks like "NC localhost 3040 < Javascript-file.js

To get around the browser to local machine security issues I want to run this from node.js with maybe socket.io-client if possible, but I don't know the proper syntax for it.

I have seen plenty of client syntax sending hello's etc. but nothing send javascript and allowing for two-way connectivity that I can understand.

I have tried using:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');`enter code here`
socket.on('httpServer', function (data) {
console.log(data);
document.write(data + "\r\n");
socket.emit('tcp', "For TCP");
});


const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();
client.connect({ port: 3040, host: process.argv[2] });
client.on('data', (data) => {
console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
```

But I do not understand it well enough to troubleshoot why it's not working.

Any help would be wonderful, and please treat me like a baby that needs its step by step.

Cheer

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [1], We can assume socket-io isn't the perfect fit for you, because that Server you have sound like a typical tcp-socket server, not a socket.io server ( which requires special headers ) or a web-socket server.

So you only needs "net" library to do the job.

```
const net = require('net');

// module to send a message to TCP-socket server and wait for the response from socket-server
const sendAndReceive = async (client, message) => {

  client.write(message);

  let response = null
  await ( new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    client.on('data', function(data) {
      response = data;
      resolve()
    });
  }))

  return response;

}

// send a single message to the socket-server and print the response
const sendJSCode = (message) => {

  // create socket-client
  const client = new net.Socket();
  client.connect(3040, 'localhost', async function() {
    console.log('Connected');

    // send message and receive response
    const response = await sendAndReceive(client, message)

    // parse and print repsonse string
    const stringifiedResponse = Buffer.from(response).toString()
    console.log('from server: ', stringifiedResponse)

    // clean up connection
    client.destroy()

  });


}

sendJSCode('var Out; \n Out="TheSky Build=" + Application.build \n\r')
```

- This script will:

  - Initiate a socket client
  - on connection successfully, client sends a message
  - client receives back response from that message
  - client prints response to terminal
- Note that TheSkyX has a limitation of 4096 bytes for each message[2], any more than that and we will need to chunk the message. So you may want to keep the js-code short and precise.
- that snippet I gave is minimal, it doesn't handle errors from server. If you want, you can add `client.on("error", .. )` to handle it.
- Your point of connecting to the socket server directly from browser is very intriguing, unfortunately it is not allowed by modern browsers natively due to security concerns [3](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100827/why-no-support-for-tcp-sockets-in-javascript)

[1] [https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not:~:text=That%20is%20why%20a%20WebSocket%20client,to%20a%20plain%20WebSocket%20server%20either](https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not:%7E:text=That%20is%20why%20a%20WebSocket%20client,to%20a%20plain%20WebSocket%20server%20either).

[2] [https://www.bisque.com/wp-content/scripttheskyx/scriptOverSocket.html#MSearchField:~:text=set%20to%204096%20bytes](https://www.bisque.com/wp-content/scripttheskyx/scriptOverSocket.html#MSearchField:%7E:text=set%20to%204096%20bytes)

Comment: Thanks this is really helping to point me in the right direction. I gather  sendJSCode(var Out; \n Out="TheSky Build=" + Application.build \n\r') is the var for the JS code to be sent..how would I code this to send a JS file like camera.js (it's in the same directory) also is there a good website to go for hints on the syntax of Net

Comment: for reading the content of "camera.js", I recommend "fs" library. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readfilesync-method/  . And for resources about "net" library: https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to send it to the TCP server and not read it. The difference in the current setup is we are sending javascript to the server but what I need to do is send a JS file to the server. I have tried sendJSCode('./camera.js') and also sendJSCode('var Out; \n Out="./Camera.js" \n\r')  sorry if I'm missing something basic.

Comment: you can use "fs" package to read content from another file as string, and pass that content to the sendJSCode() module. `const fs = require('fs');  const jsToSend = fs.readFileSync('./camera.js');  sendJSCode(jsToSend); `

Comment: Works great.... thank you so much you have filled in the gaps in my knowledge that will now allow me to carry on with this project. Thanks for your patience and your time. :)

Comment: No sweat friend :) Hope you get that project done with flying colors.